# PHP Model and Services: how about multiple results?

Tags: php, oop

Just learning OOP, I discovered this slideshare:

http://www.slideshare.net/aaronsaray/enterprise-php-mappers-models-and-services

At slide 26 he creates a class named `UserService`, that invokes a mapper proxy with MySql (slide 25) and passes it a `User object` (shown at slide 24).

This seems to me "perfect"; in effect we "get" an `User Object` populated and mapped with database (or others database).

My issue is: If I have multiple returns (imagine to have 100 records on database and we need to print all of them).

How manage this scenario? How "populate" `100 User objects?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, reusing the mapper makes sense:

```
class UserMapperMysql {
    public function mapUser(User $user, array $dataset) {
        $user->id = $dataset['id'];
        $user->firstname = $dataset['firstname'];
        $user->lastname = $dataset['lastname'];
        $user->email = $dataset['email'];
    }
}
class UserRepositoryMysql {
    protected $_pdo;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost", "root", "password");
    }
    public function findById($userID) {
        $sql = "select id, firstname, lastname, email";
        $sql .= " from user where id = ?";
        $stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($userID));
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
    public function findByTop100() {
        $sql = "select id, firstname, lastname, email";
        $sql .= " from user order by activity limit 100";
        $stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
}
class UserService {
    public function fetchById($userId)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $mapper = new UserMapperMysql();
        $repository = new UserRepositoryMysql();
        $mapper->mapUser($user, $repository->findById($userId));
        return ;
    }
    public function fetchByActivity()
    {
        $repository = new UserRepositoryMysql();
        $mapper = new UserMapperMysql();
        $dataset = $repository->findByTop100();
        $list = array();
        foreach ($dataset as $row) {
            $user = new User();
            $mapper->mapUser($user, $row);
            $list[] = $user;
        }
        return $list;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean (re)create a User object foreach row? No issue of memory?

Comment: Sure, its a lightweight object, serialize it and see. But if you have that concern you should look at Flyweight pattern.